# Get-ADGroup difference between properties 'member' and 'Members'?

Tags: powershell, active-directory

When I execute '**Get-ADGroup -Identity "groupname" -Properties member,Members**', as long as the group has members both properties look identitcal.  If the group has no members **Members** will be an empty list but **member** won't return as if it doesn't exist.

According to bing chat, it says the difference is: `"In the context of Get-ADGroup cmdlet, the member property returns the distinguished name of each member of the group while the members property returns a collection of objects that represent the members of the group. These objects can be users, groups, and computers."`

However, I don't know if this is correct since, as noted before, they both appear to be identical lists.  I'm wondering what the real difference is between these values.  Thanks!

Comment: `Members` is not an actual AD Attribute just something that the `Get-ADGroup` cmdlet can use as an "alias" for the `member` attribute. In fact if you try to use `-Properties members` with `Get-ADObject` you would get an error. I would say trust less in "bing" and trust more in trial an error.